# Property 'utm' does not exist on type 'typeof

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, leaflet

Saudações,

Sou iniciante tanto em Angular quanto em Typescript eu venho do java.
Eu estou fazendo o front-end de um projeto usando Angular 10, nele uso *leaflet* para exibir mapas porém surgiu uma necessidade de instalar a dependencia [(leaflet.utm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.utm/v/0.0.4), mas não faço ideia de como distinguir o "L" das duas bibliotecas (leaflet e leatlet.utm).

instalação do módulo:

```
>  npm i leaflet.utm@0.0.4
```

meu import

```
...
import * as L from 'leaflet';
...
```

Linha de codigo que pretendo usar

```
var item = L.utm({x: 467486.3, y: 4101149.3, zone: 30, band: 'S'});
```

Tenho a excepção

```
> Property 'utm' does not exist on type 'typeof import("../node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Voce instalou os tipos desse plugin `utm`? `npm install --save @types/leaflet.utm`

Comment: obrigado irmão, funcionou. vc merece uma estátua.